# Use of Uri IsWellFormedUriString when Uri TryCreate works perfectly

Tags: c#, .net, url, .net-2.0, uri

I am using code:

```
Uri.TryCreate(sURL, UriKind.Absolute, out URI)
```

which works fine.

Do I need to call `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(sURL, UriKind.Absolute)` ? I mean I want to know what is the use of `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` when `Uri.TryCreate` works perfectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` calls `TryCreate` internally as well as calling [Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring.aspx) so the results may differ from simply calling `TryCreate`.

From ILSpy

```
public static bool IsWellFormedUriString(string uriString, UriKind uriKind)
{
    Uri uri;
    return Uri.TryCreate(uriString, uriKind, out uri) && uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString();
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring.aspx)

> [Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString] indicates whether the string used to construct this Uri was
>   well-formed and is not required to be further escaped.

Comment: Two questions:  1.  Is there any possibility that any string will pass Uri.TryCreate and not Uri.IsWellFormedUriString ? 2.  You said "so you don't need an extra out variable", the third variable "out Uri result" is compulsory in all three declarations of Uri.TryCreate. So, how do I call Uri.TryCreate without it?

Comment: Updated my answer. I took a look at IsWellFormedUriString in ILSpy and shows that it also calls IsWellFormedOriginalString unlike simply calling TryCreate.

Comment: Whay can't I use IsWellFormedOriginalString for relative uri?

Comment: @Max - I haven't tried but are you sure you can't? Looking at the source, this seems like it shouldn't be an issue http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,fb5ba9a46b2384ae . Are you sure you're testing a valid string (valid being in accordance of RFC 2396 and RFC 2732) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?

Comment: Sorry, it wirks. I try to validate relative uri with hash in the end (/discussion/page.aspx?DiscussionID=13&PostID=1#post4) using IsWellFormedUriString. It retruns false. How to validate uris with hash?